# How to get textfield value in Arduino?

Tags: php, html, arduino

I have created a web page by Arduino. Now I want to create a textbox, then I want to check the value posted in that checkbox with an ith index in an array which was created before. Now, if the textbox value matches with the array value, up servo motor.

How to do that?

Comment: Break your problem into smaller parts and check [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just tell me, how do i insert a textfield value to a variable in arduino

Comment: Demanding "Just tell me" is no way to get help from volunteers.

Comment: Two of your 3 questions have negative votes. You really should consider reading [ask]. Don't you think you should learn how to ask a question on a technical problem in a way that does not offend people? being able to break a problem down into smaller problems and formulating questions and instructions in the most detailed, precise and unmistakable way is THE key skill a programmer needs, maybe next to knowing how to operate google

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with www.google.com?

It's a great tool to get information.

Open www.google.com in any web brower.

Then enter "arduino webserver text". Once you enter t of text the auto-completion will suggest "arduino webserver text input". Click on it.

The website will refresh, presenting you the search results for the key words you just entered.

Now read the first link (any other link will do as well)

[HTML Text Box to Send Text to Arduino Web Server | Starting ...](https://blog.startingelectronics.com/html-text-box-to-send-text-to-arduino-web-server/)

Sounds promissing right? Click on it!

> An Arduino and Ethernet shield are used as a web server to host a web
>   page that contains a text box. Text can be typed into the web page
>   text box using a web browser and sent to the Arduino by clicking a
>   button on the web page.

Oh wow! Looks like this is your lucky day!

And hey, if you don't like reading you'll even find youtube videos where people talk to you!